# What is the open/read file equivalent to storing values in a variable?

Tags: python, file, csv, variables

I have a piece of code that goes like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     taxids = [1204725, 2162,  1300163, 420247]
     desired_ranks = ['kingdom', 'phylum', 'class', 'order', 'family', 'genus', 'species']
     path = 'taxids.csv'
     main(taxids, desired_ranks, path)
```

I have a file which contains each of these numbers (and a lot more) separated by a line which looks like this. myFile.csv contains:

```
1204725
2162
1300163
420247
```

I was wondering how do I read in my file to replace the 'taxids' variable?

[SOLVED] Working code is below.

```
with open('justTaxidsCOG0202.csv', 'r') as file:
    stringtaxids = file.read().replace('\n', ', ')
    taxids = stringtaxids.split(', ')
```

Comment: Your file contains text, and that is what's being read. You either need to parse that text to get the result you want, or alternatively, don't use your own text format and stick to something like JSON

Comment: Thank you Juanpa, your comment provided me enough information to solve it without blatantly giving me the answer! I learnt something :)

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects), if you want to read all the lines of a file into a list you can use `list(f)` or `f.readlines()`. Downside to this approach is that you get the newlines at the end of each taxid. Another approach that handles that is commented out below.

```py
with open('myFile.csv', 'r') as file:
    #this method includes the newlines (\n) at the end of each taxid 
    taxids = file.readlines()
    #this method strips those newlines, still giving you a list
    #taxids = file.read().splitlines()
```

Comment: Thank you Scott. I've fiddled around with it and still cannot get it to be successful.

Comment: No problem! Does `taxids = file.read().splitlines()` not work?